# Subkey generation in OMAC1/CMAC with XTEA?

Tags: modes-of-operation, key-size, blocksize, cmac

All implementations of CMAC that I have found so far use a block cipher with the same key and block size. However, XTEA enciphers a 64 bit block by using a 128 bit key.
If `E_XTEA(key,block)` is the encipher function and `k` is my main key, CMAC produces a temporary key `k0` from an all-zero block:

```
k0 = E_XTEA(k,0)
```

CMAC derives two other keys from `k0` with the same length as `k0`, `k1` and `k2`.
This derivation uses a constant `C` which is "*completely determined by the number of bits in a block*"

There are two problems:

- `k` is 128 bit long, but `k0`,`k1` and `k2` are only 64 bit long because they depend on the output of the 64 bit encipher function.
- Is `C` really determined by the block size instead of the key size?

My assumption is that `E_XTEA(k,0)` is used to generate a pseudo-random block, and I can use `k0 = concat(E_XTEA(k,0),E_XTEA(k,1))` to generate a pseudo-random block of the right size. But I don't know if this is correct  or which `C` to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at how the keys $K_1$ and $K_2$ are used in [CMAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38B/SP_800-38B.pdf) (pdf, Section 6.2):

> 4. If $M_n^*$ is a complete block, let $M_n = K_1 \oplus M_n^*$; else, let $M_n = K_2 \oplus (M_n^*||10^j)$, where $j = nb-Mlen-1$.

They are combined with message blocks using XOR. So they must be equal in length to the block size, not the key size (if different), of the cipher.

Similarly, then, $C$ is determined by the block size.

Comment: Thanks, you are completely right. `k1` or`k2` is only used for a xor operations and is not the key for the cipher function.